# Use COM interface without statically linking to library

Tags: c++, windows, com, dynamic-linking

This may be a bit of a newbie question, but I just don't know! To use a function in a DLL that might not be present on the system I can use `LoadLibrary` and then `GetProcAddress`. But how can I do the same thing for a COM interface? I can include the header file for the declarations, IID's, and so on.. but I don't want to link against the accompanying library using `#pragma comment(lib, "blabla.lib")`.

(I'm trying to use the `WICImagingFactory` interface, and that requires linking against windowscodecs.lib to compile)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to fight against linking windowscodecs.lib. Linking against it doesn't result in implicit linking as you would get for a non-COM library.

You still need to call [`CoCreateInstance()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686615.aspx) just as you would for any COM object. Think of this as being runtime binding equivalent to `GetProcAddress`.

Comment: Ha! You are right, I renamed `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsCodecs.dll` to `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsCodecs.bak` (after taking ownership grrr) and my application runs fine except that `CoCreateInstance` fails, which is no problem, I've got some fallback mechanism to good old GDI functions :) Thanks heaps!

Comment: You could make CoCreateInstance succeed by updating the registry entries for your CLSID to point to WindowsCodecs.bak :)

Comment: Ok nice to know, but I was just testing how my application would respond when WindowsCodecs.dll is not found, removing it entirely felt so crude ;)